# One-parameter semigroup of operators of a $C^*$-algebra applied to positive self-adjoint element

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, semigroups-of-operators

Let $X$ denote a complex $C^*$-algebra and $\{Z(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a $C_0$-semigroup of operators on $X$.

Let $x\in X$ satisfy have $x=x^*$ (x is self-adjoint), such that its spectrum satisfies $\sigma(x)\subset [0,\infty)$.

Then under what conditions does it follow that $[Z^*(t)]=[Z(t)]$, and $\sigma(Z(t)x)\subset [0,\infty)$?

Comment: What does it mean for an element of a Banach space to be self-adjoint?

Comment: let me re-phrase it. $X$ is a complex $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: What is $Z^\ast(f)$? And what is $f$?

Comment: Sorry sir it was typing error. $Z^*(t)$ is adjoint operator of $Z(t)$.

Comment: How do you define $Z^\ast (t)x$? $x\in X$ and not from $X^\ast$...

Comment: actually I need to show $Z^*(t)=Z(t)$. $x=x^*$, $Z^*(t)x^*=Z(t)x$. does it make sense now?

Comment: I was assuming $Z\ast (t)$ denotes the usual adjoint operator (acting on the dual space of $X$) of $Z(t)$. Then they are usually acting on different spaces and this does not make sense. Do you have a different definition of $Z\ast(t)$?

Comment: Sir its almost justified for my case. I am restricting the situation accordingly, like the case when $X=X'$ (dual space). can you please guide me about the spectrum? do we have some relation? if $\sigma(x)\subset [0,\infty)$ then does it imply that $\sigma(Z(t)x)\subset [0,\infty)$??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11999/discussion-between-gul-e-hina-and-andras-batkai)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the fact that I do not understand some parts of your question, self-adjoint elements with positive spectrum define a positive cone in your $C^\ast$ algebra. Positivity-preserving semigroups in $C^\ast$ and von Neumann algebras were extensively studies, you should consult the chapter written by Ulrich Groh in the book

[W. Arendt, A. Grabosch, G. Greiner, U. Groh, H. Lotz, U. Moustakas, R. Nagel (ed.), F. Neubrander, U. Schlotterbeck
One-parameter Semigroups of Positive Operators
Springer, 1986.](http://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/one-parameter-semigroups-of-positive-semigroups/Nagel%20One-parameter%20Semigroups%20of%20Positive%20Operators.pdf)

Comment: yes it actually defines a positive cone in $C^*$-algebra. I want isotonic $Z(t)$. i.e. whenever $x\geq 0$, $Z(t)x\geq 0$. and the order relation is defined above.